how to add Poll in Quill Editor
I'm building a chat Application in that chat app I also need to add a Poll I want whenever a user presses  ('/') in the editor, poll popper should open, after selecting the poll from the popper, we need to type question, and objective in the editor, I m little bit getting answer but I need a perfect solution.
Making Quill Editor Poll, in the Quill editor pressing ('/') how to Implement Poll. I am building a chat application that requires a poll feature. I want the poll pop-up to appear when the user presses the forward slash ('/') key in the editor. Once the user selects the poll from the pop-up, they should be able to type their question and objective in the editor. Although I have found some solutions, I am still looking for the perfect solution to implement a poll feature in the Quill editor.
